# How can a cylinder have more gas than its own volume?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, states-of-matter

I saw the following problem in a book:

In S.T.P., a balloon of diameter 1.004m has to be filled with H2 gas.At 27°C,a cylinder with volume 1 m^3 is filled with H2 gas having 2000 kPa pressure.How many balloons can be filled with the gas in the cylinder?

The volume of the gas at S.T.P. in the cylinder comes out to be 17.962 m^3.Now, it's written in the book that all of the gas can't be taken out,1m^3 of volume of gas can't be taken out as it is the volume of the cylinder itself.

I have two questions.

1. How can the volume of the gas be greater than the volume of the cylinder at S.T.P.?Doesn't the gas contain the same amount of volume as the cylinder?
2. Why can't we take out all of the gas out of the cylinder?

Please consider that I am quite new to this platfrom and I don't know a lot about the rules or how to ask questions.Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

1. For an ideal gas, volume and pressure are inversely proportional at fixed temperature. This can be seen from the ideal gas law $PV = NkT$ where at constant temperature the right hand side is a constant. So when the pressure increases, the volume decreases, i.e. you can "fit more gas" inside the cylinder at higher pressure.
2. When we open the gas cylinder, the pressure inside is greater than the atmospheric pressure outside (and in the balloon). That means there will be a net force pushing gas out of the cylinder. But when the pressure inside the cylinder becomes equal to the surrounding atmosphere, the forces balance and there is no further mechanism that pushes gas out of the cylinder. To get the rest out, we would need a pump, but even very good pumps cannot extract *all* the gas inside, as that would lead to a perfect vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can always fit more gas than cylinder's vol by increasing pressure that is until it bursts.
   2.while taking gas out the pressure that you applied before will decrease with PV=nRT until the pressure inside cylinder becomes equal to the atmospheric pressure outside i.e.when diffusion stops .(diffusion:any gas will flow from higher concentration to lower )